# how to pass data to next view controller while still loading data from previous view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

How can pass data to the next view controller when, in the background the previous viewcontroller is loading that data i need.

is there a method i can use to send the data to the second viewcontroller when done loading while being already on the second view if that makes sense?

ive tried Prepare segue but that doesnt work.

and i also tried this

```
[photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"%@",photo.objectId);
            _PFObjectId = photo.objectId;

            AddProductDetailsViewController *sendData = [[AddProductDetailsViewController alloc]init];
            sendData.objectId = photo.objectId;

        }
    }];
```

was hoping once its done itll send that photo.objectId over but its not

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the full method that i need to send over inside prepareForSegue and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
[photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"%@",photo.objectId);
        _PFObjectId = photo.objectId;
        //You should not alloc it again once the view controller is pushed or presented .If it is already in stack
        AddProductDetailsViewController *sendData = (AddProductDetailsViewController *)[[self.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];

        //instead of sending object Directly like this sendData.objectId = photo.objectId  create a method and call after completion
        [sendData pushObjectId:photo.objectId];
    }
}];
```

Hope this helps you